# ExpandableListView error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, expandablelistview

i have an ExpandableListView and when I click a child  the background-color is set to green. This works fine but when I expand another group the previous background-color  is set to the first element of the opened group and disappears from the previous item. This seems a bug but I don´t know how to solve it, someone has experimented the same?
Here my simple code:

This is the the row element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/equipRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And Here the onChildClick function:

```
private void ItemClick(){
        this.getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                RelativeLayout rL = (RelativeLayout)v;
                TextView eView = (TextView) (((RelativeLayout)v).findViewById(R.id.equipRow));

                eView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(150,66, 165, 29));
                exListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: it's not a bug ... it's a feature ... try to read about ListView on Android (especially about reusing views by Adapters ...) you should rather store selected items somewhere and color items in getView based on stored selection ...

Comment: Ok thx this is the way I´m using but I don´t know the objective of this feature,